# Connect host network from a window remote desktop machine

Tags: networking, macos, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I have a web server running on my Mac on port 8080(localhost:8080), and I'd like to test it from a windows machine.
I have a Mac machine (Host) and a Microsoft Remote Desktop connected windows machine (VM). I know there are many posts/videos on how to access the VM network from Host machine.
But I'd like to know if it's possible to access Host's network (localhost:8080) from VM's browser, something like 192.168.56.1:8080(Host's IP).

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: What virtualization software are you running?  You should be able to do this just by making sure the VM has a network card enabled and then using NAT.  This is the default configuration for Virtualbox.

Comment: I'm not sure what virtualization software is powering the windows machine. I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop app connecting to it. How do I find out what VM is the windows machine?

Comment: Sorry, I read that as your Mac is the host and the guest VM is running on your Mac.  Seems that is not the case?

Comment: That’s actually a very good point. I only connect the VM using Microsoft Remote Desktop, and never thought of where the VM is running. I believe VM is not running on the host machine, in this case anyway to let VM machine accessing host machine’s network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address `192.168.56.1` is a local address that is only reachable
from inside your local network.

If the VM is inside your local network, and if its network adapter
uses Bridge or NAT to the same router, then certainly this address is
reachable.

However, if you are doing the RDP to an external address (the target
is not `192.168.56.x`), then the remote computer cannot see your computer.
It can connect to your router by its public internet IP, but for your
router to transfer the connection to your computer will require
[Port Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)
the port `8080` to your computer.